# Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskDrive is not correctly working. How to Get unallocated Disk Space in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, disk

I am using VMWare ESX.
Normally ,  I found out that there is about 52GB of unallocated space on the F disk.  I am using MBR disk.

Get-Volume | select DriveLetter,FileSystem,DriveType,SizeRemaining,Size | Format-Table

```
DriveLetter FileSystem DriveType SizeRemaining          Size
----------- ---------- --------- -------------          ----
            NTFS       Fixed         159502336     524283904
C           NTFS       Fixed       10554765312   53160701952
D           NTFS       Fixed       31295717376   34356961280
F           NTFS       Fixed      248218685440 2199021727744
E           NTFS       Fixed       20982292480  171793129472
G           NTFS       Fixed       49961721856  107372769280
I                      CD-ROM                0             0
A                      Removable             0             0
```

$disk variable

```
DeviceID           Caption                              Partitions Size         Model                               
--------           -------                              ---------- ----         -----                               
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 VMware Virtual disk SCSI Disk Device 1          171793198080 VMware Virtual disk SCSI Disk Device
```

$partitions

```
Name             NumberOfBlocks                 BootPartition                  PrimaryPartition               Size                          Index                        
----             --------------                 -------------                  ----------------               ----                          -----                        
Disk #2, Part... 335533527                      False                          False                          171793165824                  0
```

$allocated

```
171793165824
```

$unallocated

```
32256
```

Here is my script :

```
# Query the Win32_DiskDrive instance representing the physical disk
$disk = Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskDrive -Filter 'Index = 2'

# Find all associated partitions
$partitions = $disk |Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_DiskPartition

# Calculate total allocation for configured partitions
$allocated = $partitions |Measure-Object -Sum Size |Select-Object -Expand Sum

# Calculate the remaining void
$unallocated = $disk.Size - $allocated

Write-Host ("There is {0}GB of disk space unallocated" -f $($unallocated/1GB))
```

Comment: Allocated is not the same as the amount of space used on the drive. Why not just use `Get-Volume`?